# Access to PHP script being denied by WAMP Server

Tags: php, windows, apache, cgi-bin, dbase

I have thoroughly checked for an answer to this question but it seems like not one off the countless answers has helped me.

I would appreciate some guidance.
I have a website that I am accessing remotely via the clients public IP address.  I have installed and configured WAMP Server with Apache 2.4.27.  The machine is also running PHP 5.6.31.

**What I am trying to do** is allow a tax payer to upload supporting documentation to a folder using a script that I wrote called *upload.php*.  I have tested the program on my local environment and it works.  I should add that the bulk of the code for the website is written in a compiled `dBASE` executable that resides in the `cgi-bin`.

I am able to navigate to the page in which I allow the user to select a file and upload it, but when I click the upload button, I get an **error message** that states.

```
You don't have permission to access /upload.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31 Server at 24.148.115.174 Port 8000
```

I have configured my virtual host to allow access to the *Wamp64/www directory*.

I have no idea why this is **not working**.  If you need to see the `httpd.conf` file, let me know.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I visited the IP address you gave and when you write the port at the end, it gives the error you've written. I doesn't matter which file you are in

Comment: Are you sure that the port is configured correctly?

Comment: I am able to access the exe file  that is in the cgi-bin on port 8000.  I believe I have the port configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel foolish.  My vhost.conf file was still set to 
     VirtualHost *:80.

I changed it to 
     VirtualHost *:8000

and that fixed the problem.  Thank you to everyone for their advice.

Answer (score 0):

try use: `chmod 777 upload.php` maybe your apache user don't have permission to access upload.php.

Comment: The problem is not about that specific file. The whole 8000 port is not working.

Comment: If `chmod 777` is ever the answer then you're asking the wrong question.